# how to scale dynamic range voltage to 1-5 volt

Tags: voltage, amplifier

how can i make circuit that scale input voltage that have dynamic range to 1-5 volt output?

[image: http://upic.me/show/46750774]

the circuit will have Vref+ and Vref- as maximum and minimum for Vinput and then scale to 1-5 volt output

output equation wil be like Vout = (((Vin - Vref-)/(Vref+ - Vref-))*4)+1

ex. if I have Vref+ = 6V, Vref- = -2V, and Vin = 3V as input and the output will be 3.5V
and if I change Vref+ to 4V, Vref- to -1V and Vin still 3V output must be 4.2V

Comment: Please supply a formula for \$V_{out}\$ that includes the two reference voltages and the input voltage

Comment: This is no as easy as you might think. How fast does this amplifier need to be (How quickly do the inputs change or what are the inputs' frequency bandwidths) and how much error can you tolerate in the output?

Answer (score 2):

The key to this solution is to use the Vref input of a suitable A/D converter in order to scale the input voltage. This is not an all analog solution; but unless your frequency, resolution and/or latency requirements are too restrictive ...

1) Use a differential amplifier to take the difference between Vref+ and Vref-. This will be the Vref input to an A/D converter with a suitable reference voltage range (possibly [ADS7816](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbas061/sbas061.pdf) for example). The differential amplifier will need to scale the output so that it falls within the allowable Vref max and min range of the A/D converter. The use of the Vref input sets the full-scale value for Vin taking care of the division in your transfer function (A/D output at full-scale when Vin = Vref+, and at 0 when Vin = Vref-). Note that you may not find an A/D converter that allows a Vref input all the way down to zero, but the ADS7816 is specified clear down to 100mV (Vref range 100mV to 5V).

2) Use a differential amplifier to take the difference between Vin and Vref-. Scale this the same as the differential amplifier in step 1. The output of this amplifier is the voltage input to your A/D converter.

3) All that is left then is to take the output of the A/D converter, convert it back to analog with a D/A converter, and apply necessary offset and gain with an op-amp to achieve a 1-5V range (calibration pots may be useful). A micro-controller would simplify the interface between the two converters, but it really doesn't need to do anything but time the conversions and transfer the data.

One of the main advantages to this solution over reading Vref+, Vref- and Vin separately into an A/D converter is that this method utilizes the full range of the A/D converter (assuming same resolution in D/A converter) for the output regardless of how close Vref+ is to Vref- (within the Vref min limits mentioned above). In other words, the number of steps (resolution) for Vout as it ranges from 1 to 5 volts will be the full range of the converters. If separate conversions are used for Vref+, Vref- and Vin; the number of steps  available for Vout will be limited to the number of steps between the A/D conversions of Vref+ and Vref-.

Since there is only one conversion per sample with this solution, you will not need to worry about sampling and holding all three inputs at the same time, or what errors may result if they are sampled at separate times.

Another advantage of this method is speed. Since the microcontroller does nothing but time the conversions and transfer the data, the main limiting factor is the speed of the converters. For other solutions, if the microcontroller needs to do math (especially division), that time would need to be considered.

A useful app note on using Vref for scaling: [VOLTAGE REFERENCE SCALING TECHNIQUES](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa008/sbaa008.pdf)

Analog Devices has a useful tool for designing and testing differential amplifiers [HERE](http://designtools.analog.com/dtDiffAmpWeb/dtDiffAmpMain.aspx).

For greater accuracy and stability, you might consider using [instrumentation amplifiers](http://www.analog.com/en/specialty-amplifiers/instrumentation-amplifiers/products/index.html) for your differential amplifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function I derived is the same as the OP added to the question: -

\$V_{OUT} = 4\times(\frac{V_{IN}-V_{REF-}}{V_{REF+}-V_{REF-}}) + 1\$

The first thing is subtract \$V_{REF-}\$ from \$V_{IN}\$ which is a trivial exercise with an op-amp. Then comes the harder part and that is scaling this intermediate result against a base of \$V_{REF+}-V_{REF-}\$.

This probably could involve an analogue multiplier configured for division. The divisor would be \$V_{REF+}-V_{REF-}\$ and this would be expected to be a positive number i.e. ref+ is bigger than ref- but I suspect a circuit could be made that works thru an inversion where ref- is bigger than ref+ BUT watch out for when ref+ = ref- because then the divisor is zero.

Assuming that ref+ is always bigger than ref-, I would use another simple op-amp subtractor circuit to form the 2nd intermediate result. Then I'd go against my analogue ideals and cheat with a PIC or other similar MCU.

Now that I'm cheating I'd throw away the op-amps that did the subtraction to give the two intermediate results and feed \$V_{IN}, V_{REF+}\$ and \$V_{REF-}\$ into a PIC to do the maths.

Multiply \$(\frac{V_{IN}-V_{REF-}}{V_{REF+}-V_{REF-}})\$ by 4 and add 1. Job done.

Comment: What is an "analogue multiplier configured for division"? How would you configure a multiplier circuit to do division?

Comment: @ThePhoton off the top of my head I can't give a part number but I remember seeing an analogue multiplier chip that could perform division.

Comment: Do you know any cheap log amps? I found AD538 which is configurable for multiplication, division, and exponentiation. But it uses log amps internally and costs @ $40-50 in small quantities.

Comment: @ThePhoton no, not off the top of my head. Are you looking for one? I kind of did change my mind half way through my answer and go for an MCU to do all the math BTW. Maybe it's not that clear?

Answer (score 0):

So we've figured out the transfer function we're looking for is

\$V_{OUT} = 4\times(\frac{V_{IN}-V_{REF-}}{V_{REF+}-V_{REF-}}) + 1\$

Unfortunately this means dividing one voltage by another dynamically, which is actually not such an easy thing to do.

One way would be to use log amps and subtraction to do the division. Unfortunately, log amps tend to be pricey. The ones I know about cost over $10 per amplifier in hobbyist quantities.

Analog Devices provides a single-chip solution in the [AD538](http://www.analog.com/en/special-linear-functions/analog-multipliersdividers/ad538/products/product.html) (This might be the part mentioned by Andy in his answer). This part uses log and andti-log amps internally, and costs over $40 each in low volume.

One possibly lower-cost [solution](http://freecircuitdiagram.com/2010/11/14/tc9400-analog-division-ratiometric-measurement/) I found in a web search is to use voltage-to-frequency and frequency-to-voltage conversion. It's fairly easy to divide frequencies using counters, so this gets around the problem of having to divide voltages.

If your latency, accuracy, and precision requirements allow it, the cheapest solution is likely to be analog-to-digital conversion, numerical division with digital logic, and then re-conversion to the analog domain. Note that even in the digital world, division is a multistep process that may require several clock cycles, so there is likely to be significant delay between input and output with this approach.